# eth-lightwallet example for keystore.addHdDerivationPath()

Tags: eth-lightwallet

Can someone give an example of how to use the keystore's `addHdDerivationPath()` method, that actually runs properly?
The code I have below (using the default `hdPath`) is giving a strange error

```
lightwallet.keystore.deriveKeyFromPassword(password, function(err, pwDerivedKey) {
    let ks = new lightwallet.keystore(seed, pwDerivedKey);
    console.log(ks.isDerivedKeyCorrect(pwDerivedKey));//true
    ks.addHdDerivationPath("m/0'/0'/0'", pwDerivedKey, {curve: 'secp256k1', purpose: 'sign'});
})
```

EDIT: OK, I solved it myself - turns out my `hdDerivationPath` is wrong - it had a "/i" at the end (in my local version), which somehow caused the KS's `encSeed` to reset to `undefined`, and the error above.
The code snippet I posted above actually works.

Comment: `encryptedStr` is undefined; including how you're getting `encryptedStr` could help others find the problem.